# Generating code with gii in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to create a new model, after setting the virtual host I couldn't acces the url for gii generator.

My Virtual Host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/backend/web"
    ServerName admin.product 
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I access the gii generator now?

> The gii url looks like
>   http://hostname/index.php?r=gii
>
> reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

Comment: 1. If you are on Windows, assure you set up your hosts files right.
2. Assure that you can access the main page of your backend application.
3. Then assure that you have your Gii module included into backend app's config.

Comment: @AlexanderDyachkov Thanks for your response!

Comment: No prob) Glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I could access gii via url

> admin.product/gii

Note : I use pretty url.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are on Windows, assure you set up your hosts file right.
2. Assure that you can access the main page of your backend application.
3. Then assure that you have your Gii module included into backend app's config.

Comment: Most helpful! Thank you.